# None of the forms are submitting

Tags: forms

I have a strange problem - on my local installation none of the forms are getting submitted.

I can access forms and when I click submit, page just reloads and nothing happens. That applies for all configuration forms, as well as node save/edit forms. Strangely, I can log in.

I don't really know where to look. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can happen when there are problems with your local .htaccess file -- it might be that Apache locally is not set up to read .htaccess files, or there may be an error in the file, or it may be missing altogether.

If the issue is specifically with the login form, you might be having issues with HTTP/HTTPS switching if your site is configured to attempt to negotiate the scheme, but your local server is not configured to serve HTTPS.

Comment: Thank you Les, but login form is actually the only one working. .htaccess works, and I checked for https redirection. Anything else on your mind?

Comment: Actually POST method to the form's URL returns 404 status

Comment: mod_rewrite was disabled! I would never have thought about it, since pretty URLs were working. Les, your answer pointed me in the right direction, thank you.